# how to dynamic resize split or table view controllers?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, split

I have split controller or table view controller (i wrote project in 2 ways) with 2 columns like on image:

[image: here is UISplitView]

I need to allow users to resize width of left and right columns. I mean that i can click or touch on vertical seperate line between left and right view and move it to change width.

How to do that?

Comment: are you using UISplitViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the outstanding custom split [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController), it does exactly what you want.

By the way for the splitViewController Apple says "*The width of the left pane is fixed at 320 points in all orientations. Users cannot resize either pane of a split view*."

You can check the reference from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41).

So you need to write a custom component or use the awesome control above.